# How to allow for complex URLs on a Django-rest-framework viewset

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have a `Scheme` viewset, with a detail route called `optimize`.  The definition looks like this:

```
@detail_route(methods=['get’])        
def optimize(self, request, pk=None):
    pass
```

I’m using the `DefaultRouter()` to generate the URL, which ends up being `/schemes/:id/optimize`.  I want to have a 2nd method on my viewset that runs optimize on a specific location, so the url might look like `/schemes/:id/optimize_by_location/:id`.

How do I set up this function in my views, where there are 2 levels to the route?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible with the default router. So you should:

- [implement a custom router](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#custom-routers) (or use a third party package)
- or manually register your `/schemes/:id/optimize_by_location/:id` url (probably easier but less generic):

More info about this in django rest tutorial: [Binding ViewSets to URLs explicitly](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/6-viewsets-and-routers/#binding-viewsets-to-urls-explicitly)

```
    from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
    from .views import MyViewSet

    optimize_view = MyViewSet.as_view({'get': 'optimize_specific_location'},)
    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^schemes/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/optimize_by_location/(?P<loc_id>[0-9]+)/$',
            optimize_view),
    ]
```